# putting #warning inside #define's body

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, mingw

In a header that should be able to compile in C and C++ files, in Visual Studio (2010) and MinGW (32-bit - v3.4.5, 64-bit - v4.5.0) I am trying to minimize the size by changing each one of such line (there are many of them):

```
// for symbol A
#ifdef __GNUC__
# warning Symbol A is deprecated. Use predefined const cnA instead.
#else
# pragma message("Symbol A is deprecated. Use predefined const cnA instead.")
#endif

// Same for B
// Same for C
// . . .
```

to

```
// define this once:
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define X_Warning(x) #warning "Symbol " x " is deprecated. Use cn" x  // (1)
#else
# define X_Warning(x) __pragma(message("Symbol " x " is deprecated. Use cn" x "))
#endif

// and use like this:
X_Warning("A")
X_Warning("B")
X_Warning("C")
```

or, at least to this:

```
// define this once:
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define Y_Warning(x) #warning x   // (2)
#else
# define Y_Warning(x) __pragma(message(x))
#endif

// and use like this:
Y_Warning("Symbol A is deprecated. Use predefined const cnA instead.")
Y_Warning("Symbol B is deprecated. Use predefined const cnB instead.")
Y_Warning("Symbol C is deprecated. Use predefined const cnC instead.")
. . .
```

But the line marked with (1) doesn't work.

`__pragma` is Microsoft's equivalent for `#pragma` to use in this kind of situations.

1. What is the right way to do this?
2. Is it even possible for MinGW/gcc?
3. is `__GNU__` right symbol to use for such things?

**P.S.** I forgot to mention that A, B, C.. are #define-ed symbols. In that case it is not possible to do with my old MinGW v3.4.5 (at least in my case with this particular configuration). And @Edwin's answer is correct.

But _Pragma is supported by newer versions of MingW and, thanks to @Christoph for an answer, it is possible to do as follows:

```
// define this once:
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
# define X_Warning(x) DO_PRAGMA( message "Symbol " #x " is deprecated. Use cn" x )
#else
# define X_Warning(x) __pragma(message("Symbol " x " is depricated. Use cn" x ))
#endif

// and use like this:
#ifdef A
  X_Warning("A")
#endif
#ifdef C
  X_Warning("B")
#endif
#ifdef B
  X_Warning("C")
#endif
```

Marking as deprecated seems to work in some cases, but not for me. It requires you to define deprecated symbols before their usage which is not my case and beyond my control.

Comment: depricated -> deprecated

Comment: you cant do it:  You can't have a preprocessor directive as the result of macro expansion

Comment: Doesn't MSVS support the #warning directive, too?

Comment: No, MSVS doesn't support #warning. Isn't it part of any C or C++ standard? It supports #error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In msvs 2010 there is this :

```
 #pragma deprecated( identifier1 [,identifier2, ...] )
```

don't know about other compilers

and microsoft specific:

```
__declspec(deprecated) void func1(int) {}
__declspec(deprecated("** this is a deprecated function **")) void func2(int) {}
__declspec(deprecated(MY_TEXT)) void func3(int) {}
```

Comment: The GCC equivalent is `__attribute__((deprecated))`, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html .

Comment: +1, I think it is probably best to address the real problem (deprecating symbols) then to hack through with "message". It has the extra bonus that, AFAIR, for gcc this extension is present since a long time, probably also for the oldish 3.4.5.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer to the posted question. Thanks.  But, looks like I forgot to mention that A, B, C were #define-ed symbols and now I made them const int cnA, ... constants.

Comment: @Seyran: You can deprecate macro names. Place the macro name in quotes or else macro expansion will occur.

Answer (score 4):

GCC supports the C99 `_Pragma` operator and even comes with [example code for your use case](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#index-pragma_002c-diagnostic-3216).

Comment: +1 but I'd have doubts that this will work for the oldish MinGW v3.4.5. And one should perhaps add that, yes, `__GNUC__` is correct macro to test for the presence of gcc, any flavor.

Comment: @Jens: a quick google search showed that fixes for `_Pragma` issues went into gcc-3.2.x; it works with cygwin-gcc 3.4.4, so I suspect mingw-gcc 3.4.5 should also be ok; why one would use such an old compiler release is beyond me, though...

Answer (score 3):

You can not construct #pragma or #warning with macro but i think you can do something like:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define Y_Warning(x) message x
#else
# define Y_Warning(x) message(x)
#endif

#pragma Y_Warning("Symbol A is depreboned. Use predefined const cnA instead.")
#pragma Y_Warning("Symbol B is depronated. Use predefined const cnB instead.")
#pragma Y_Warning("Symbol C is deprecuted. Use predefined const cnC instead.")
```

Comment: you can construct `#pragma` directives through macros: C99 added the `_Pragma` operator, which is supported by gcc

Comment: MinGW v3.4.5 doesn't support _Pragma and at this project I can not upgrate it unfortunately.

Comment: And looks like gcc doesn'texpand Y_Warning